# Use dynamic URLs to 'activate' extra CSS

Tags: php, dynamic

Firstly sorry if this is a common question but I couldn't  find anything on Google and it doesn't seem overly documented.

I'm currently making a portfolio for myself showcasing my graphic design and things. I love how it looks but I do realise it looks quite dark in comparison to other websites. The text in the navigation bar especially is also quite small, but I don't want to change it.

Instead I would like to have a small iOS style switch at the bottom of the page which when clicked would take the user to an alternate version of the page in question, or just a version with different CSS applied to it. I could then set the backgrounds lighter, the text bigger, etc. The simple but tedious solution would be to make each page four times, one with big fonts and light backgrounds, one dark and small, etc. but this isn't ideal. I was wondering if I could make something more like:

```
portfolio.co.uk/home?light=on&text=big
```

As far as I know dynamic URLs (as I believe they're called) are a PHP thing but I have as little experience with PHP as a man without experience of PHP. I was wondering if this task would be possible without getting too complex and if maybe there'd be a way of even creating a cookie so that a recurring visitor wouldn't have to navigate to their preferred version every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the query string parameters to determine which stylesheet to load.

Basically, create a general stylesheet that is always loaded, regardless of which theme you are using.  Then, put theme-specific rules into separate stylesheets and use PHP `if` statements to determine what markup to send to load the appropriate page.

```
<head>
    <link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?php echo $_GET["style"] == "iPhone" ? "iPhone" : "normal" ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   ...
</head>
```

Note, I use the if-check (the ternary operator `? :`) rather than just use the string directly from the query string because I want to have a way of sending a default if the user changes the query string and makes a mistake.  If you have multiple themes you want to use, you can set up a switch statement and store the appropriate filename in a variable that you reference in the `link` tag.

```
$stylesheet = "default";
switch ($_GET["style"]) {
    case "iPhone": $stylesheet = "iPhone";
    case "bigBold": $stylesheet = "bigBold";
}

<link href="<?php echo $stylesheet; ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

## How to Use:

To add this code into your PHP page, place the switch code at the top of the page (or, better yet, in it's own `include`d file.

### *Top of the page*

Set up your page like this:

```
<?php 
    $stylesheet = "default";
    switch ($_GET["style"]) {
        case "iPhone": $stylesheet = "iPhone";
        case "bigBold": $stylesheet = "bigBold";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<?php echo $stylesheet; ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
<html>
```

This code would need to be added to every page where you wanted to use alternate styles, so the better option is to separate this code into a file that can be `include`d on all pages.

### *As an included file*

Create a file named `stylesheetSelector.php` and add this code to it:

```
<?php 
    $stylesheet = "default";
    switch ($_GET["style"]) {
        case "iPhone": $stylesheet = "iPhone";
        case "bigBold": $stylesheet = "bigBold";
    }
?>
```

Then, in your PHP page:

```
<?php include_once('stylesheetSelector.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<?php echo $stylesheet; ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
<html>
```

Do this on all pages, then, if you ever decide to add additional themes, you can simply add the information to the `stylesheetSelector.php` file and it will be available on EVERY page that `include`s it.

**CAVEAT:** This needs to be done in a `.php` file, or your web server needs to use PHP to handle `.html` files, otherwise you'll see the PHP code in cleartext (it won't be interpreted).

Comment: That is one option to go with, which would remove the need for a "switch" at the bottom of the page to change themes.  It sounds like the OP wants to allow anyone to switch, not just iPhone specific, so this would work for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's greatly appreciated. I'll play around and try what you said. I should try and learn a bit of this PHP stuff anyway. ;)

Comment: Sorry for being a pain, but how and where in a typical HTML document would this go? The link tag I understand, but what about the other PHP?

Comment: And yes, my server seems fine with PHP in a straight HTML document. :D

Answer (score 1):

You could change the CSS stylesheet depending on the querystring yes ... something like this in php :

```
if ($_GET['light'] == 'on'){
   echo "<style>something here</style>";
}else {
   echo "<style>something else</style>";
}
```

`$_GET['light']` gets the querystring value for `light`

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with it. :D

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the include php file .  When you use the include <'stylesheetSelector.php'>, how would you include the path within <>.  Since we are using separate file kept on a server, which may not have the file in the same directory ?

read this link about conditional css stating that it is better to check browser abilities rather than selecting based on browswer.  The reason is you won't have to update or change code as browser update abilities.

http://www.conditional-css.com/

Comment: I have no idea what you;re saying, sorry. The method I'm using works fine. PHP is executed on the server so whatever browser is being used, all it needs to support is multiple `link` tags to style-sheets and the `important` CSS majig.